# Faulty C# code involving doubles and integers

Tags: c#, integer, double

```
    for (iy = 0; iy < h; iy++)
    {
        double angy = (camera.fov_y / h) * iy;
        for (ix = 0; ix < w; ix++)
        {
            double angx = (camera.fov_x / w) * ix;
            //output[ix,iy].r = (int)Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y);
            //output[ix,iy].b = (int)Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y); 
            double tr = (angx / camera.fov_x) * 255D;
            double tb = (angy / camera.fov_y) * 255D;
            Console.Write("({0},{1})",Math.Round(tr),Math.Round(tb));

            output.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(tr), 0, Convert.ToInt32(tb)) );
            Console.Write(".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Can anyone see any immediate problems with that code?
The variables `tr` and `tb` always evaluate to 0.

I'm happy to provide more information if it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given the types for the other variables - in particular, what are the types of `camera.fov_x` and `camera.fov_y`? If they're both integers, then the lines initializing `angx` and `angy` will be evaluated using integer arithmetic.

This can be fixed by casting one of the operands:

```
double angy = ((double) camera.fov_y / h) * iy;
```

The `fovy` and `fovx` variables are already doubles though, this isn't the problem.

Could you give a complete example of this, which we can compile and test ourselves?

EDIT: Koistya Navin's edit is overkill. You only need one operand of an expression to be a double for the whole thing to be computed using double arithmetic. (It needs to be the right expression though - if you do `(a/b) * c` and cast `c` a double, the multiplication will be done with double arithmetic but a/b might still be done as integers.)

Here's the listing changed appropriately to make sure double arithmetic is used everywhere it should be:

```
// Changed loops to declare the variable, for stylistic purposes
for (int iy = 0; iy < h; iy++)
{
    // Changed here - cast camera.fov_y
    double angy = ((double) camera.fov_y / h) * iy;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < w; ix++)
    {
        // Changed here - cast camera.fov_x
        double angx = ((double) camera.fov_x / w) * ix;
        //output[ix,iy].r = (int)Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y);
        //output[ix,iy].b = (int)Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y); 
        double tr = (angx / camera.fov_x) * 255D;
        double tb = (angy / camera.fov_y) * 255D;
        Console.Write("({0},{1})", Math.Round(tr), Math.Round(tb));

        output.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(tr), 
                                               0,
                                               Convert.ToInt32(tb)) );
        Console.Write(".");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I've changed a few lines around since I posted, but here is the complete source code.

Program.cs - http://pastebin.com/f4c133638
Classes.cs - http://pastebin.com/d18b37a35
MiscFunctions.cs - http://pastebin.com/febb33ca

Comment: By the way, I know the entire code is pretty overkill for what it produces, but I'm aiming to make a ray-tracing engine, so that's where  the `ang` bits and `camera.fov` bits come in ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't forget to cast your integers to doubles. For example:

```
for (iy = 0; iy < h; iy++)
{
    double angy = ((double) camera.fov_y / h) * iy;
    for (ix = 0; ix < w; ix++)
    {
        double angx = ((double) camera.fov_x / (double) w) * (double) ix;
        output[ix,iy].r = (int) Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y);
        output[ix,iy].b = (int) Math.Round(255 * (angy / camera.fov_y);
        double tr = (angx / camera.fov_x) * 255D;
        double tb = (angy / camera.fov_y) * 255D;
        Console.Write("({0},{1})",Math.Round(tr), Math.Round(tb));
        output.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.FromArgb(
            Convert.ToInt32(tr), 0, Convert.ToInt32(tb)) );
        Console.Write(".");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

#### Quick Reference:

```
 int * double = double
 int / double = double
 double * int = double
 double / int = double

 int * int = int
 int / int = int // be carefull here!

 1 / 10 = 0 (not 0.1D)
 10 / 11 = 0 (not 1)
 1D / 10 = 0.1D
 1 / 10D = 0.1D
 1D / 10D = 0.1D
```

Comment: While I suspect the problem is integer arithmetic, that line is a bad example: angx is already a double, so that line isn't the problem IMO. (Also 255D is a more compact way of writing (double)255.)

Answer (score 0):

It know it's not part of your original question, but using SetPixel(..) is not very efficient and could be a problem if you are planning to use it in a ray-tracing engine.

You might want to use the LockBits() method, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c/190395#190395) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541331/effective-way-of-making-negative-of-image-without-external-dlls/552013#552013) for more details. They other way to go is to access the data using "unsafe" C# code, which allows you to uses pointers to the data. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702188/can-this-code-be-optimised) for more info, I got a ~x2 speed-up by using "unsafe" code.